# Is "average speed" equal to $|\text{average velocity}|$?

Tags: terminology, related-rates

So, apparently,
$\text{instantaneous speed} = |\text{instantaneous velocity}|$.

But what about *average speed*? Is $\text{average speed} = | \text{average velocity} |$?

I can't find suitable explanations online and I keep finding contradicting explanations as well!

Comment: If you go somewhere and back, your average speed could be anything, but your average velocity will be zero.

Comment: Yes, that's true. So I'll rule out average speed = |average velocity|

Comment: $\text{average speed} = \text{average}\;|\text{velocity}|$

Comment: huh? So it is true? @Blue

Comment: |average velocity|$\leq$ average |velocity|

Comment: What does the average refer to outside of |  |

Comment: @user71207 it is to make the distinction between absolute value of the average velocity and the average of the magnitude of the velocity. For example, $|v_{avg}|=| v_0+v|/2$ while average|velocity|$= (|v_0|+|v|)/2$

Answer (score 1):

Average velocity and average speed have one common difference that while average velocity can be zero(that is when you return back to the spot you started from) when average speed is not zero. Also when a man turns back while walking his average velocity not only becomes negative but can also deviate from the absolute value of average speed. Thus there are many cases when $$\text{average speed} = | \text{average velocity} |$$

Answer (score 0):

Average speed is given by $$\frac{\displaystyle\int_{t_1}^{t_2}|v(t)|\,dt}{t_2-t_1} $$ where $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}|v(t)|\,dt$ is total distance traveled and $t_2-t_1$ is the change in time.